# unable to navigate to submenu, space between menu and submenu

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have two working sites and added css3 transition effect in menu

I stucked into one issue, i am not able to navigate to submenu. when mouse is on the menu 'our program' , following is the behavior of sites

http://localhosting.asia/slimagain/

it show menu , there is visually enough space in menu and submenu, so not able to navigate.

http://localhosting.asia/slimagain1/

it show menu , there is visually no space in menu and submenu, i am easily navigate to submenu.

Both the navigation code is similar , there is no specific code for space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to solve my problem , it was because of wrong value of top of submenu.

Answer (score 1):

Well, since this is tagged jQuery, do it with jQuery and add some delay before hiding the menu. :)
Something like this:

```
var ddTimer;
$(document).on('mouseenter','#navigation > li', function() {
    $('.sub-menu').hide();
    clearTimeout(ddTimer);
    $(this).find('.sub-menu').show();
}).on('mouseleave','#navigation > li', function() {
    var $dropdown = $(this).find('.sub-menu');
    ddTimer = setTimeout(function() {
        $dropdown.hide();
    },500);
}).on('mouseenter','.sub-menu', function() {
    clearTimeout(ddTimer);
});
```